# What to include in agreement with a Ghost Writer. .

Tags: publishing, legal, non-fiction, contracts, ghostwriter

I am exploring engaging a Ghost writer to partner with me on the development of a non-fiction (well, mostly) business book.

What are the critical elements of the agreement that need to be included?

Comment: Just a reminder that while you may get some interesting answers, we are *not* lawyers here.

Comment: I'd recommend speaking with a lawyer who specializes in this type of thing and have them draw up a contract for it.

Comment: Not looking for a legal opinion. A lawyer drafts the wording. But the content comes from me. I am looking for the critical elements from a writers perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of factors that come up and should be negotiated at the beginning.

You can structure your agreement for a flat fee (most common) or for a percentage of royalties (less common), or a combination.

Regardless of the payment arrangement, you'll also have to decide on certain legal/copyright and process issues:

- name credit (you'll either have to specify that you be included as co-author, mentioned in the acknowledgments, or are waiving all rights);
- royalties (waive or include);
- who is doing the research (this is a big chunk of the work so be sure to sort that out before you start);
- interview access (how many hours the client will be available for interviews/collaboration);
- payment schedule (many ask for, say, 1/4 of the fee upfront, 1/4 upon completion of research/interviews/outline, 1/4 upon completion of first draft, 1/4 upon completion of final draft).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

IANAL, but [he is](http://www.ivanhoffman.com/ghost.html). This should be a good starting point.

If you also want to have a look at the ghostwriter side, visit some internet sites offering this service and read their conditions (e.g. the [Penn Group](http://www.pegr.com/ghostwriter.html); first Google hit, I know nothing about them).

(While looking up services, I stumbled over [this link](http://www.americanbar.org/newsletter/publications/gp_solo_magazine_home/gp_solo_magazine_index/trialprac_ghostwriter.html). I do not understand its content, but maybe it is useful to you.)

Comment: in case those links go away, can you summarize some of their content or provide pertinent quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should identify what your goals are and start from there. You should decide just what the ghost writer's responsibilities are and also identify a means of determining whether or not those responsibilities were met.